# PySide QlistView drag and drop

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I'm trying to implement a simple drag and drop functionality from one QListView to another QListView by using PySide6.

Here ist the ui:

```
import sys

import qdarktheme
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QListView

from models.pipeline_model import PipelineListModel
from models.toolbox_model import ToolboxListModel, MyModel


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        toolbox_list_model = ToolboxListModel()
        pipeline_list_model = PipelineListModel()

        for i in range(10):
            toolbox_list_model.toolbox_items.append(MyModel(x=i))

        toolbox_list_view = QListView()
        toolbox_list_view.setDragEnabled(True)
        toolbox_list_view.setModel(toolbox_list_model)

        pipeline_list_view = QListView()
        pipeline_list_view.setAcceptDrops(True)
        pipeline_list_view.setModel(pipeline_list_model)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(toolbox_list_view)
        vbox.addWidget(pipeline_list_view)

        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarktheme.load_stylesheet())
    main_window = MainWindow()

    main_window.show()

    # Start the event loop.
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The Toolbox listmodel (where the items should be dragged from):

```
from typing import Union, Any

import PySide6
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

from models.model_data import MyModel


class ToolboxListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.toolbox_items: list[MyModel] = []

    def data(self, index: Union[PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex, PySide6.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex],
             role: int = ...) -> Any:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            model = self.toolbox_items[index.row()]
            return model.x

    def rowCount(self, parent: Union[PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex, PySide6.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex] = ...) -> int:
        return len(self.toolbox_items)
```

The target listmodel (where the toolbox items shall be dropped):

```
from typing import Union, Any

import PySide6
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

from models.model_data import MyModel


class PipelineListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.toolbox_items: list[MyModel] = []

    def data(self, index: Union[PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex, PySide6.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex],
             role: int = ...) -> Any:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            model = self.toolbox_items[index.row()]
            return model.x

    def rowCount(self, parent: Union[PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex, PySide6.QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex] = ...) -> int:
        return len(self.toolbox_items)
```

and finally the shared datamodel:

```
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyModel:
    x: int
```

Even though, the dragEnabled is set to True and the receiver QListView is set to accept the drop, the drag operation doesn't even start.

What am I doing wrong here? How to do the d'n'd operation correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [model view documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#enabling-drag-and-drop-for-items) (which I strongly suggest to read in its entirety), you must override the [`flags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) function, because the default behavior only makes items enabled and selectable.

Setting the `Drag` flag on the view only *allows* drag operations, but only the model can tell *what* items can be dragged.

If you want to allow an index to be draggable, you must also provide the [`ItemIsDragEnabled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) flag:

```py
class ToolboxListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if index.isValid():
            flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags.ItemIsDragEnabled
        return flags
```

Then, depending on the behavior you want on the target model, you may need to override flags to accept drops *onto* existing items (to overwrite items), or implement other functions as shown in the documentation about [subclassing QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing), since it doesn't support resizable lists by default.